# Minimized Window in WPF cannot be restored by dragging data object over it in WIndows Taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create two non-modal windows
2. Minimize one window
3. Start draging DataObject from the window that is not minimized to the minimized window in the Windows taskbar

Expected: Minimized window should be restored

Actual: Minimized window is not restored

When you drag something over a minimized window in the Windows taskbar the minimized window is not restored. It seems, this is reproducible only when you drag something between two windows from the same process. If I drag a files from the desktop or anything else from other app over the minimized window, it is restored as expected.

This looks like a bug in .net. I can see the same behavior in other .net apps (Em Client, Visual Studio)

I made small sample project that reproduce the issue https://github.com/ekalchev/DragOverWindowsTaskbarBug

I am looking for workaround or explanation if this is the expected behavior.